# how to deal with files whose names are flags

Tags: linux, unix, flags

I was wondering how to deal with files whose names are flags, like '-a', '-f' etc. I can't pass them as arguments to programs like `rm` or `ls`, because they are interpreted as flags, and doing `rm *` or `ls *` just runs those programs with the flags of the filenames (for obvious reasons). How do I pass flags as ordinary filenames in program arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common trick is to prefix with `./`:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ touch ./-a ./-b ./-c
edd@max:/tmp$ ls -l ./-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 0 May 22 21:07 ./-a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 0 May 22 21:07 ./-b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edd edd 0 May 22 21:07 ./-c
edd@max:/tmp$ rm ./-*
edd@max:/tmp$ ls -l ./-*
ls: cannot access ./-*: No such file or directory
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Comment: Also: rm-- -a will work on some, but not all UNIX systems.  The double dash translates to "end of options".  Meaning the getopt() call will not try to make -a an option instead of a filename, which is your intent.

Comment: To add to what @jimmcnamara said: "The special argument `--` forces in all cases the end of option scanning."  (quoted from "Using the getopt function" http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt)